# Open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, closed under addition and subtraction.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, real-numbers

> Let $\emptyset \neq G\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be open, such that $x\pm y\in G$ for all $x,~y\in G$. True or false? $G=\mathbb{R}.$

**Attempt**. I believe yes. Since $G \neq \emptyset,$ there is $x\in G$ and therefore $0=x-x\in G$. Also, $G$ is not bounded: since $x\in G$, we get that $nx\in G$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Finally, i shall prove that if $0<z<x$ then $z\in G$ (and we are done). I am stuck on this part though.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have $0 \in G$, then since $G$ is open, you have $(-a,a) \subseteq G$, for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, with $a > 0$.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $x/n \in (-a,a)$ for some sufficiently large positive integer $n$, hence $x/n \in G$. But then, since $G$ is closed under addition, it follows that $x \in G$.